# Can Siri be set to read characters?

Tags: iphone, messages, settings, siri

So my iPhone 5 digitizer broke, and since I have an upgrade coming up soon, I'm trying to do without a working phone until i can get the new 6. My problem is, however, that I have some websites I need 2FA for, and it's set to send codes to my cell phone via text message. Siri is still completely functional, so I've been making phone calls and dictating text messages through her, but when I ask her to read a message with a 2FA code, she not only speeds through the code so fast i need to listen multiple times, but she also doesn't diferentiate between lowercase and uppercase letters.

Is there any way I can set Siri to:

```
A. Read slower
B. Read letters as uppercase or lowercase
```

And can I change these settings with Siri, not going to the Settings app?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, no such settings exist for Siri.

Comment: Ok, thanks @tubedogg. Can you think of any other ways for me to get around this problem, or am I left high and dry until I upgrade?

Comment: I can't, no. I think your best bet at this point is to upgrade as soon as possible.